# Python inverted index efficiency

Tags: python, performance, search-engine, inverted-index

I am writing some Python code to implement some of the concepts I have recently been learning, related to inverted indices / postings lists.  I'm quite new to Python and am having some trouble understanding its efficiencies in some cases.

Theoretically, creating an inverted index of a set of documents D, each with a unique ID `doc_id` should involve:

1. Parsing / performing lexical analysis of each document in D
2. Removing stopwords, performing stemming etc.
3. Creating a list of all `(word,doc_id)` pairs
4. Sorting the list
5. Condensing duplicates into `{word:[set_of_all_doc_ids]}`   (inverted index)

Step 5 is often carried out by having a dictionary containing the word with meta-data (term frequency, byte offsets) and a pointer to the postings list (list of documents it occurs in).  The postings list is often implemented as a data structure which allows efficient random insert, i.e. a linked list.

My problem is that Python is a higher-level language, and direct use of things like memory pointers (and therefore linked lists) seems to be out of scope.  I am optimising before profiling because for very large data sets it is already known that efficiency must be maximised to retain any kind of ability to calculate the index in a reasonable time.

Several other posts exist here on SO about Python inverted indices and, like MY current implementation, they use dictionaries mapping keys to lists (or sets).  Is one to expect that this method have similar performance to a language which allows direct coding of pointers to linked lists?

Comment: When you say that linked lists aren't possible in python, that's completely false. Do you mean pointer arithmetic by any chance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of things to say:

1. If **random access** is required for a particular list implementation, a **linked list** is **not optimal** (regardless of the programming language used). To access the ith element of the list, a linked list requires you to iterate all the way from the 0th to the ith element. Instead, the list should be stored as one continuous block (or several large blocks if it is very long). Python lists `[...]` are stored in this way, so for a start, a Python list should be good enough.
2. In Python, **any assignment** `a = b` of an object `b` that is not a basic data type (such as `int` or `float`), is performed internally by **passing a pointer** and incrementing the **reference count** to `b`. So if `b` is a list or a dictionary (or a user-defined class, for that matter), this is in principle not much different from passing a pointer in C or C++.
3. However, there is obviously **some overhead** caused by a) reference counting and b) garbage collection. If the implementation is for study purposes, i.e. to understand the concepts of inverted indexing better, I would not worry about that. But for a serious, highly-optimized implementation, using pure Python (rather than, e.g. C/C++ embedded into Python) is not advisable.
4. As you optimise the implementation of your postings list further, you will probably see the need to a) make random inserts, b) keep it sorted and c) keep it compressed - all at the same time. At that point, the standard Python list won't be good enough any more, and you might want to look into implementing a more optimised list representation in **C/C++** and **embed it** into Python. However, even then, sticking to pure Python would probably be possible. E.g. you could use a large string to implement the list and use [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) and [`buffer`](http://docs.python.org/c-api/buffer.html) to access specific parts in a way that is, to some extent, similar to pointer arithmetic.
5. One thing that you should always keep in mind when dealing with **strings in Python** is that, despite what I said above about assignment operations, the *substring* operation `text[i:j]` involves creating an actual (deep) **copy of the substring**, rather than merely incrementing a reference count. This can be avoided by using the `buffer` data type mentioned above.

Comment: Hey great response, thank you for taking the time.  I suppose I expected at some level that Python may not be the optimal way to approach this problem.  It was it's ease of string manipulations that drew me to it.  As far as (4), I will probably stick with a static postings list for now but I may use some type of encoding to optimize for space.  Thanks for the suggestions and your Python insight.

Answer (score -1):

You can see the code and documentation for inverted index in Python at : http://www.ssiddique.info/creation-of-inverted-index-and-use-of-ranking-algorithm-python-code.html

Soon I will be coding it in C++..

Comment: Your link seems to be broken